# How to update mysql with json array?

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays, json

I want to make cron job on my server to save my json array every 10 minutes (I want to update mysql table every 10 minutes)

The thing is that i have really nasted array which is currently really hard for me to save alone without your help!

Here is the json array:

```html
{"firstname":{"eur":14.27,"e":0.00612979},"lastname":{"eur":0.18709,"e":2.655e-05},"middlename":{"eur":617.26,"e":1.0}}
```

My table contain rows for:
name (which is the name of the example-> firstname)
So i want to update row where is the table name value same as on my example which is "firstname" or "lastname" or "middlename".

I have two more rows which contain "eur" and "e" rows.
I must input values from json array to same line row as in the example.
I know its bad explained what i want so i will try with better one.

In my SQL i have lines: (where name is already written and must stay same)
Name - EUR - E

I want to update every 10 minutes the values of EUR and E where the NAME from sql is the same as in the array data.

Here is my not working PHP CODE:

```html
$filename = "JSON-FILE-LINK";
$data = file_get_contents($filename);  
echo $data;
```

Thank you so much community!

edit:
I bet the sql code must be something like this:
UPDATE names
SET eur = $eur, e = $e, ...
WHERE name = $firstname.

Firstname is the first name of the everyobject.
And eur and e is the only values which must be changed.

How to populate json data to sql variables is the biggest problem now for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a demo. I created a table in MySQL's test schema:

```
mysql> use test;
mysql> create table mytable (name varchar(20), eur numeric(9,2), e numeric(9,2));
```

I wrote some PHP to decode the JSON into an associative array with [json_decode()](https://www.php.net/json_decode), and then use the keys and values to insert into the MySQL table I created.

```
<?php

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=test', 'root', 'xxxx');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$data = '{"firstname":{"eur":14.27,"e":0.00612979},"lastname":{"eur":0.18709,"e":2.655e-05},"middlename":{"eur":617.26,"e":1.0}}';

$sql = "INSERT INTO mytable (name, eur, e) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

foreach(json_decode($data, true) as $name => $values) {
    $stmt->execute([$name, $values['eur'], $values['e']]);
}
```

I ran the PHP at my bash command line.

```
php json-demo.php
```

Here's an SQL query showing the result:

```
mysql> select * from mytable;
+------------+--------+------+
| name       | eur    | e    |
+------------+--------+------+
| firstname  |  14.27 | 0.01 |
| lastname   |   0.19 | 0.00 |
| middlename | 617.26 | 1.00 |
+------------+--------+------+
```

---

For what it's worth, the JSON example you show is not a JSON array, it's a JSON object.

The key/value pairings inside curly braces `{ }` make it an object.

Arrays are comma-separated lists inside square brackets `[ ]`.

Comment: So my question is how i can update my table with that json object , what would be the code for updating my tables with firstname in the place in the sql table which is the "name" and contain value of "firstname" .. i put the edit on my question where i put how i think sql statement should work

Comment: I cannot visualize the change you want. Can you edit your question above and show an example of the data you want to see before and after the update?

Comment: I think I understand. You don't want to store JSON directly in the database, you want a JSON document in PHP code, and you're asking how to map it into normal columns in the table? Can you please describe your database table more clearly?

Comment: Thank you for your help. To be more clear I want to save json object values into my sql table . As you can see from my json i have diffrent name objects , that can be used to define column where to save values from objects, in my case i need to save value EUR and E into the same column which contain firstname value as row. In my database i have rows: Name, EUR , E. Name contain value of firstname,lastname,middlename, and EUR and E fields must be updated every 2 minutes on same position where the NAME IS FIRSTNAME . so FIRSTNAME EUR=14.27, LASTNAME EUR=0.18 etc...

Comment: So i want to take every json object get his name and his EUR : E values.then update my sql with that EUR;E value where the object name is same as value of row NAME in sql . I don't know how to describe it in better way.

Comment: I edited my answer to write a PHP example of decoding the JSON and inserting it into a MySQL table.

Comment: that is excatly what i am looking for, the only thing is that i have name values already inserted and i have to update the EUR and E values not insert them. But I think i will know how to do it . It would be great to have you as friend on my projects , very nice help! You are the best!!!!

Comment: You might like to learn about [UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html) or [REPLACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replace.html) or [INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: I'm sorry, I have a job and a home to take care of. I answer questions on Stack Overflow, but I am not looking for another project.